# Как в CakePHP сделать update

Tags: php

Как сделать аналогичный запрос в cakePHP?

```
$Order->OrderSource->query('update shop.order_sources set priority = 555 where order_id = 1000 and tnt = 1000);
```

Пробовал так, не выходит

```
$NewModelSource = array(
'OrderSource' => array(
'order_id' => $oldModelSource[$j]['OrderSource']['order_id'],
'tnt' => $oldModelSource[$j]['OrderSource']['tnt'],
'change' => true
),
);
$Order->OrderSource->save($NewModelSource, false, array('true'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно update только по id, а иначе он срабатывает, как insert

```
id - это id обновляемой записи, а change - это новое поле => и его новое значение
$NewModelSource = array('id' => $oldModelSource[$j]['OrderSource']['id'], 'change' => true);
$Order->OrderSource->save($NewModelSource);
```

Comment: А вообще читай документацию
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202333/cakephp-update-field